# Ruby on Rails chapter 8.2.1 uninitialized constant SessionsHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was working through the tutorial and got this error:

```
.../sample_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
`<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant SessionsHelper (NameError)
```

I tried typing the code again but to no avail, guessing I might of made a typo somewhere. I researched similar questions but they were either too different or I didn't understand the solution given.

here's the relevant code:

application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include ::SessionsHelper
end
```

sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
     flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
     render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

user pages spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before do
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar" )

end

subject { @user }

it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }
it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
it { should respond_to(:password) }
it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

...
```

Any help and an explanation of what is wrong and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is sessions_helper defined?

Comment: Try removing the 2 colons, so it's just: 'include SessionsHelper'

Comment: i think in the application_controller.rb. I'm still pretty much a novice I understand the basics but pretty clueless on the helper terminology

Comment: You are essentially including one of the view helpers in a controller. You should have a sessions_helper.rb file in app/helpers. Inside of this file should be a block starting with: module SessionsHelper. Does this file exist?

Comment: yes it does. It's empty though. Oh i just realised what was missing in that helpers file it was called SessionHelper! Error fixed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `include ::SessionsHelper` with this `include SessionsHelper`